# Top align image in <ImageBackground />

Tags: react-native, styles

I am trying to have a screen with a background image, but if the image dimensions dont work to have it fullscreen i want the image to be pinned to the top.  RN docs appear to say that resizeMode="contain" should do the trick but for some reason it still centers the image just like resizeMode="center" does.  Is there a way to do this?  The following code does not work.

```
<ImageBackground source={defaultImage} style={{ flex: 1 }} resizeMode="contain">

</ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the image with the size of your cell phone, you can use '`stretch`'.

> `stretch`: Scale width and height independently, This may change the
>   aspect ratio

of the src.

```js
<ImageBackground source={defaultImage} style={{ flex: 1 }} resizeMode="stretch">

</ImageBackground>
```

You can use `position` props if you want to maintain the image ratio and hold the image at the top.

```js
 <ImageBackground
          style={{ flex:1,position:'absolute',width:"100%",height:"100%",bottom:150,justifyContent:"flex-end",alignItems:"center"}}
          source={{ uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png' }}
          resizeMode = "contain"
        >
        <Text style={{fontSize:30,fontWeight:"bold"}}> ImageBackground</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
```

[image]